# Accessing and updating controller model within $animate .then() method - using 'this'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, angularjs-animation

I have a controller (below). I am wanting to update parts of newsCtrl from within the $animate's .then() method. But I am unable to access its variables.

As you can see from the code, my issue is when currentPage is "undefined"

So I am wondering, how can I update currentPage from within the .then() method?

AngularJS docs advise that I should use $scope.$apply (https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$apply)

But I am not using $scope on my controller, I am using "this".

```
(function(angular, $) {

    angular.module('app-news', ['ngAnimate']);

    function newsCtrl($animate) {
        this.currentPage = 0;

        this.cycleNews = function(bool) {

            // this.currentPage = 0

            $animate.leave(myElem).then(function() {
                // this.currentPage = undefined
                // $scope.currentPage = undefined
                // newsCtrl.currentPage = undefined
                $scope.$apply(function(){
                    // this.currentPage = undefined
                    // $scope.currentPage = undefined
                    // newsCtrl.currentPage = undefined
                });
            });
        }
    }

    angular
        .module('app-news')
        .controller('newsCtrl', ['$animate', newsCtrl]);

}(window.angular, window.jQuery));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` inside of your promise success function is scoped differently than `this` outside of that function.

To get around that issue, you can use [angular.bind()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bind). Todd Motto gives an example in his [article about using Controller-As syntax](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/). Your promise callback would then become something like

```
$animate.leave(myElem).then(angular.bind(this, function() {
    this.currentPage === 0 // true 
}));
```

this inside of the promise callback function is now scoped to the controller.

Answer (score 2):

The `this` inside the successful promise isn't the `this` that you think it is.

You need to assign `this` to something inside your `cycleNews()` function, e.g. `self = this;` and then refer to `self` in the promise resolution instead of `this`